# Spring RestTemplate Charset UTF-8 does not work

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, utf-8

I want to set `UTF-8` charset for Multipart/form-data resttemplate request. But It does not work. I read a lot of answers here, but I got only `???` in Rest service side.

My Server Side `RestController`. Here I get only question marks instead of `UTF-8` text:

[image]

My Client side `RestTemplate` code. Here form text is displayed correctly in `UTF-8`:

[image]

PS. When I use `Postman` as a Rest Client, the text is displayed in `UTF-8`

Comment: Have you configured [httpmessageconverter][1]?  message converters are used to marshall and unmarshall Java Objects to and from JSON, XML, etc – over HTTP.

  [1]: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: Yes, I've configured message converters in both sides.

<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried encoding?

```
map.add("message",URLEncoder.encode(emailForm.getEmailContent(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks @RahulKumar. This looks like a workaround, but it works! I URL encode the message content and subject in client side and URL decode in server side.

Comment: Yes it's a workaround but it's widely used for maintaining the special characters' support where the data is getting morphed between different call. I remember it using to put special character in DB, when DB didn't support special character type of data.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem .it solved when I used uri instead string in exchange method.

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
Map<String, String> map = generate map to keep key and value of necessaryparameters;
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("SERVICE_URL");
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    uriComponentsBuilder.queryParam(k, v);
});
URI uri = uriComponentsBuilder.build(false).encode("windows-1256").toUri();
responseEntity = new RestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```